# To push single string to an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an component called **UpdateContact** which is displayed in `dialog` window,This component is used to display the injected object  and will perform **PUT** operation of that injected object.Component Code as follows:

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="updateForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.name"   placeholder="Name"  formControlName="Name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.EMailAddresses"  placeholder="Email Address"  formControlName="Email">
        <mat-error *ngIf="updateForm.controls.email.hasError('email')>
             Please enter a valid email address
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="onClick()">Save</button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, Inject,  OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, } from '@angular/material';
import { IContact } from 'src/app/models';
import { MyService } from 'src/app/services/my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-contact',
  templateUrl: './update-contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-contact.component.scss'],
})
export class UpdateContactComponent implements OnInit {
  public updateForm: FormGroup;
  public someContact: IContact

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IContact ,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              public dialog: MatDialog,
              public myService: MyService,
              ) {} 

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
      Name: [null],
      Email: [null,[Validators.email]],
    });
  }

  public onClick() {
    this.someContact= this.updateForm.value;
    this.someContact.EMailAddresses = [];
    this.someContact.EMailAddresses.push(this.updateForm.value.Email);  
    this.myService.updateContact(this.someContact, this.someContact.Id);
  }

}
```

**Contacts JSON**

```
{
  "Id": "",
  "Name": "",
  "EMailAddresses": [""],
},
```

**Services file**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {IContact } from 'src/app/models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class MyService {

 private  baseUrl : string = '......api Url.....';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

public  updateContact(Id : string): Observable<object> {
  const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/contacts/${Id}`;

  return this.http.put(apiUrl, contact);
}

}
```

Now when i hit the **SAVE** button without making any changes in **Email** input field,I am unable to perform **PUT** operation and getting this error.

[image]

Comment: No, I'm not saying the error is because of that. I just noticed it. :)

Comment: BTW, you can initialise the material inputs inside `ngOnInit` like `Name: [data.name],      Email: [data.EMailAddresses,[Validators.email]]` and get rid of the `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: Actually i tried your solution i,e without using `[(ngModel)]` but still the same issue continuous,

Comment: But if i make any changes in `Email` i/p field, The `PUT` operation will happen fine  and error also won't occur.

Comment: Post this `myService.updateContact` as well to see if I can help

Comment: ok i will be posting soon.

Comment: I have given  `myService.updateContact`,Please check it @dcg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190743/discussion-between-dcg-and-pgh).

Comment: @PGH Check this out:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pefydi

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked for me.@PrashantPimpale

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue.Since the property **EMailAddresses** is an `array`, I just need to convert **EMailAddresses** to `string` and assign it to one variable like this:

**TS**

```
public mail: string = this.data.EMailAddresses.toString();
```

and need to display in the `template` like this:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
         <input matInput [(ngModel)]="mail"  placeholder="Email Address"  formControlName="Email">
 </mat-form-field>
```

Instead of `[(ngModel)]="data.EMailAddresses"`

Answer (score -3):

Syntactical Error is there in the form initialisation:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
      Name: [null],
      Email: [null,[Validators.email],
    });
  }
```

in the "Email" form control one Square Bracket is missing!